# Svelte/Sapper How to fetch data from internal api without giving absolute URL

Tags: svelte, sapper

I am using svelte/sapper with express.

I have an api in `routes/billing/index.js`

It needs to fetch data  from `customers/[customernumber]/detections.js`

My question is how to fetch data from internal apis with in the routes folder using relative URLs

```
async function getDataFromGateway(customerNumber) {
  if (typeof fetch !== 'function') {
    global.fetch = require('node-fetch')
  }
  const data = await fetch(`http://localhost:19052/customers/${customerNumber}/detections`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      return error
    }
    )
  return data
}
```

Is there a way to do this using relative url

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to fetch this data inside `preload`, using `this.fetch`, since that will automatically handle relative URLs the same way whether it's running on server or client:

```html
<script context="module">
  export async function preload(page, session) {
    const r = await this.fetch(`customers/${getCustomerNumber(session)}/detections`);
    const data = await r.json();

    return {
      foo: data.foo
    };
  }
</script>
```

If that's not possible for whatever reason, you might need to configure an environment variable, e.g. `BASE_URL`:

```js
async function getDataFromGateway(customerNumber) {
  if (typeof fetch !== 'function') {
    global.fetch = require('node-fetch')
  }
  const data = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/customers/${customerNumber}/detections`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      return error
    }
    )
  return data
}
```

Comment: Thanks Harris. Appreciate your time. But is there a way we can use `this.fetch` outside  `<script context="module">`,  in a javaScript file

Comment: No, because it's contextual — it resolves URLs relative to the route that's being prepared

Comment: Been discussing this in sapper discord channel. Isn't making an http request a bit of an unnecessary overhead and inefficient / slow? What about calling into the same code that `/customers/${customerNumber}/detections` triggers if you know you are on the server, and do the fetch if you know you are on the client?

Comment: I'll be writing an RFC soon that addresses this very topic