# How to make an API call in Svelte using a relative url?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a svelte application and would like to make an API call to my server from JavaScript. *The key is that I want to use a **relative url*** i.e., instead of:

```
fetch("https://example.com/foo);
```

I want to do:

```
fetch("/foo");
```

but if I try to do that I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot use relative URL (/$) with global fetch — use `event.fetch` instead: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/web-standards#fetch-apis
    at globalThis.fetch (file:///Users/xxx/code/xxx-svelte-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:35:10)
```

This issue is documented [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/8536). Its a long thread but as far as I could understand the solution offered is to use the [load](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load) method. However, this does not work for me as the API call needs to be made dynamically (AJAX).

I tried prefixing all my urls with [`window.location.origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/origin) e.g.:

```
fetch(window.location.origin + "/foo")
```

but now the code does not build:

```
ReferenceError [Error]: window is not defined
```

I don't understand why would Svelte compiler give this error. Granted `window` does not exist in Node.js but it exists in the browser. And Svelte code is supposed to run in the browser!

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60118489/svelte-sapper-how-to-fetch-data-from-internal-api-without-giving-absolute-url) post btw but again the solution offered does not help me.

What is the way out here? There ought to be one. Setting the base url using environment variable is not a solution for me as it creates a lot of hassle - the app may be running on localhost, in dev, test, prod etc.

Comment: They are giving you a handy URL to your problem, did you try anything in the docs? I think they are giving you full flexibility by overwriting the methods like `export GET(event) { event.url = 'https://example.org/' + event.url; }`. But you might aswell just define a variable like `const baseUrl = 'https://example.org/';`. Remember: In an environment outside of a browser, there is no global `window` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as follows:

`+page.server.js`:

```
/** @type {import('./$types').PageServerLoad} */
export async function load({ params, url }) {
    const slug = params.slug;
    console.log(url);
    return { slug: slug, origin: url.origin };
}
```

`+page.svelte`:

```
<script>
/** @type {import('./$types').PageData} */ 
    export let data;    // data is special keyword and will contain data returned from page.server.js. see: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load
```

`data.origin` will have equivalent of `window.location.origin`. Now prefix all relative urls with `data.origin` i.e.:

```
fetch(data.origin + "/foo");
```

This pattern has to be repeated on every `+page.svelte` in the application.

The documentation was not very clear to me but now I (think I) get it.

Comment: That is not how to do this. You are just circumventing an error and sending useless requests on the server (the result is not awaited during server-side rendering), then on the client the request is sent again.

Answer (score 1):

> And Svelte code is supposed to run in the browser!

It's not. By default it runs on the server on first load ([SSR](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/glossary#ssr)), after that the browser takes over.

If you want to run code only in the browser, you can do that in [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#onmount), which never runs on the server (unlike `onDestroy`). Here you can then also just use `fetch('/...')` because the browser provides the rest. You can also check whether the code runs in the browser via SvelteKit's [`browser` flag](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-environment-browser).

Also, for the given example which has nothing dynamic in it, that could just as well be run in the `load` function. As the error already points out, you there have to [use the `fetch` provided](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#making-fetch-requests) by the event object passed to the `load` function.